# linear independence of two polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $K$ be a field and $f, g \neq 0$ Polynomials out of $K[x]$ with different degrees. Show that $f, g$ are linear independent.

I tried to use the definitions but i don't really know how to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it would go like this: assume f and g are linearly dependent over K, then there are a, b in K not all are zero such that: af + bg = 0, so f = ba^(-1)g, and this means deg(f) = deg(g) so m = n but it was told that m is not n.

Comment: Why can i assume, that there are $a, b \in K$ so that $af + bg =0$?

Comment: Because if you assume that f,and g are linearly dependent then there exist two scalars in the field F called a and b such that not all are non-zero and af + bg = 0

Answer (score 1):

Let $P=\alpha f+\beta g$ and assume that $\deg f<\deg g$ then differentiate $P\;\;\;$ $\deg f+1$ times you find simultaneously $\beta =0 $ and $\alpha=0$ and conclude.

Comment: Short and sweet and spot on! +1

Comment: $\ddot\smile{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Compute the coefficients of $\alpha f + \beta g$. Can they all be zero?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $\deg f<\deg g$. Then for any non-zero constant $\deg \alpha f=\deg f<\deg g$. So...?

> Since $\deg \alpha f<\deg g$, we cannot have $\alpha f=g$ for any constant $\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let the degrees of the polynomials be $n$ and $m$ with $n>m$.  Then both polynomials can be represented by a vector in $K^n$.